# I want to install inkscape version 0.9.2 but when i am installing it is giving me error

Tags: ubuntu

I am running this command

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape=0.9.2
```

giving me error :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '0.9.2' for 'inkscape' was not found

How to forcefully install that version ?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you have?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? It doesn't look programming-related to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a typo. On the [Inkscape releases page](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.2/) there is no version `0.9.2`. The correct version is probably `0.92.2` or `0.92`

Comment: this is also giving me the same error

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to install this specific version but the install guide can be found here: https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-0.92.5/gnulinux/ubuntu/ppa/dl/

If you don't need that specific version I would use the snap or AppImage: https://inkscape.org/release/1.2.2/gnulinux/

ppa's are not really meant for this use.

Comment: I am running my code in python and was working fine with old version but in inew version is not working